# Testing important implementation details

Tags: unit-testing

I'm implementing a `key -> value` associative container. Internally it's a sorted binary tree, and I want to make sure it's balanced so that `find` operations are sure to be `Olog(n)`. The problem is that this is an implementation detail that is entirely private to the class, and I can't readily measure it from outside.

The best I can think to do is to benchmark my `find` operations - if they operate in linear time it's probably because the tree is unbalanced - but that seems far too inexact, and I'd feel better if I had a more direct way to measure.

What design/testing patterns are out there that might be helpful in these sorts of situations?

Comment: You could mock/spy the object in order to check if the correct calls are made. The tested object (mastering the algorithm) should be injected so. You would be able to assert if unexpected calls are avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extract the balanced tree to it's own class, and test that class. In that class the balanced-ness is a feature of the class and could expose something like depth which would let you inspect it and assert that the tree remains balanced.

Comment: Ooh, neat idea. I knew someone here would think of something clever.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that you are testing an implementation detail. The problem here is that a bad implementation also produces the correct output, it just takes longer. This means that the only measurable unit is time.

What I would do is similar to what you propose: create a big collection of data and structure it in a way that a good implementation should be able to find what you're looking for in a matter of moments and a bad implementation has to go through your entire collection before finding it.

This could translate to having thousands of elements and searching for the element that's last in line. You could structure it in a way that a good implementation should find it at the top of the tree and thus find it very quickly while a bad implementation should find it somewhere at the bottom, thus taking time to find it.

Many frameworks have an option to specify a timeout so if you set this to a low enough value and you have plenty of data in your collection, you can weed out slow-running implementations like that.

Comment: "Many frameworks have an option to specify a timeout" What is a timeout?

Comment: It will automatically fail the test once the test execution time has passed the amount you defined.